# Unwanted scrollbar appears on JQM pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile

![JQM page scrollbar][1]
Even the content's length doesn't cover the whole page, I see a vertical scrollbar on the page and I'm sure that it is not caused by my own CSS.

What could cause this behavior?

Thanks in advance

[1]:

Comment: share a screenshot plz?

Comment: Or even better an example of your page.

Comment: I think this is a css problem. Listview is obviously been modified. This error could be caused by margin or padding in the wrong place. Use firebug plugin for Firefox or Chrome (or any other browser HTML DOM inspector) and inspect page div css.

Comment: @Gajotres Hi, this problem occurs on all the JQM pages, and it is not isolated to one page :(

Comment: @Bandpay: Is your site online, I can take a look at it. It would take me few minutes to find a problem.

Comment: @Gajotres Hi again, thank you for your kindness, but the site is not online yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing a blank scrollbar, or are you seeing a ton of "white space" below your page?  If you are seeing a blank scrollbar, it is caused by css such as the example below. (Not sure what it looks like in jquery-mobile).

```
  html,body{
   height:100%
  }
  html{
   overflow-y:scroll
  }
```